# Using CSS Grid to achieve an unbalanced Masonry Grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I am playing around with the layout of a product page and I am trying to get the right hand column to flow together a bit more. The link I have below should demonstrate the structure I am trying to achieve. The only thing I have left to do is to get the yellow to move up next to the green. I was wondering if there was an easy way to achieve this.

https://codepen.io/JBConcepts/pen/GRKXYpq

HTML

```
 <div class="container">
     <div class="box viewer"></div>
     <div class="box price"></div>
     <div class="box info"></div>
     <div class="box config"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
}

.box {
  min-height: 20px;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.viewer {
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
}

.price {
  height: 300px;
  background: green;
}

.config {
  height: 600px;
  background: yellow;
}

.info {
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  /*  Set order  */
  .viewer {
    order: 2;
  }

  .price {
    order: 1;
  }

  .config {
    order: 3;
  }

  .info {
    order: 4;
  }
}
```

I am not sure where to go from here but I will keep looking. I need the separation and the html structure so that I can make it flex on mobile and set the desired order.

[image: example]

Comment: Please draw (in some paint editor) how the scheme should look.

Comment: Added an example image

Comment: if you use grid, it allows element to span through colums or rows, but **it needs to be set from css**.  Your example forked https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/aboaXwg , see this usefull reminder https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ and https://gridbyexample.com/

Comment: This is NOT A grid (there are no rows) ...so CSS-GRID is not appropriate here.